# Only "child-schema" triggers on post save mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to add a `.post('save')` middleware with mongoose, but only the child schema "gets run." Why isn't the parent schema answering? I get a response with:

```
ContentChildSchema.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('ChildSchema: ' + doc)
})
```

But I don't get a response with:

```
ContentParentSchema.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('ParentSchema: ' + doc)
})
```

ContentModel.js:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

const ContentChildSchema        = mongoose.Schema({
  blockId: { type: String, default: () => `block-${ nanoid(7) }` },
  element: { type: String, default: 'div' },
  content: { type: String },
  contentEditable: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  order: { type: Number },
  children: [],
})

const ContentParentSchema       = mongoose.Schema({
  blockContainerId: { type: String, default: () => `block-container-${ nanoid(7) }` },
  page: { type: String, required: true },
  element: { type: String, default: 'div' },
  contentEditable: { type: Boolean },
  children: [ ContentChildSchema ],
  order: { type: Number },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

ContentChildSchema.add({
  children: [ ContentChildSchema ]
})

const ContentParentModel        = mongoose.model('Content', ContentParentSchema)

ContentChildSchema.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('ChildSchema: ' + doc)
})

ContentParentSchema.post('save', (doc) => {
  console.log('ParentSchema: ' + doc)
})

export default ContentParentModel
```

ContentController.js:

```
ContentRoute.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const page            = req.body.page
    const children        = req.body.children
    const content         = req.body.content

    const doc             = new ContentParentModel()

    doc.page              = page
    doc.children.push({ content: content })

    doc.save()

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: 'add content',
      message: 'Innhåll har lagts till.',
      data: doc
    })
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: 'add content',
      message: 'Något gick fel med att lägga till innehåll.',
      errorData: error.message
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why do you have this code? You already have it in your parent schema? `ContentChildSchema.add({
  children: [ ContentChildSchema ]
})
`. Remove it and try

Comment: @SuleymanSah It's for recursive children. Tried without it right now, and still only the ChildSchema responds. Thanks for your comment though! :)

Comment: You need to add await in front of `doc.save()`. Can you try that way?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Just tried adding await in front of doc.save(), still parentschema doesn't get triggered. Thanks so much for trying to help! :)